# Is it possible to detect if flag -txindex is enabled using RPC?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc

Using JSONRPC, how do I detect if a node has `-txindex` enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getindexinfo` RPC call to list (and get the status of) all the available indexes since version 0.21 (currently in rc3).

On my local `bitcoind` with (only) `txindex` enabled, here is the output:

```
$ bitcoin-cli getindexinfo
{
  "txindex": {
    "synced": true,
    "best_block_height": 660887
  }
}
```